# Prove that Z/13Z[i] is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm really confused on this one. Can anyone explain this concept to me better? How would I go about proving this?

Comment: You are writing $\left(\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}\right)[i]$ correct?

Comment: @JohnMartin the text says it the way I have written. I'm not sure what the different would be

Answer (score 2):

The various notations (including the one I prefer: $\mathbb Z[i] / 13\mathbb Z[i]$) mean: ring of "complex integers" of the form $a+bi$, $a$ and $b$ integers, modulo the principal ideal generated by $13$. The point is that $13$ is not a prime element in $\mathbb Z[i]$; for example, $3+2i$ is not divisible by $13$ (try writing $3+2i = 13 (a+bi)$ with $a,b$ integers, if you can!) - but $(3+2i)(3-2i)$ is divisible by $13$. So you found non-zero elements in the quotient ring, whose product equals "zero" in the quotient ring.

Comment: That I can follow. So (3 + 2i)(3 - 2i) = 0 (because its divisible by 13) which means its not an integral domain.

Comment: Yep - that's it.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes so much more sense

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see this is to calculate $(\bar{5}+i)(\bar{5}-i)$.

Comment: easier: $(\bar 3 + 2i)(\bar 3 - 2i)$ :-)

Comment: @mathguy: But I don't understand how to do that? I'm really confused by this concept. Do I just distribute and get 13? What does that mean?

Comment: It means that you took the product of two non zero things and got something equal to 0, i.e. the ring is not an integral domain

Comment: @JohnMartin Can you explain it a little more step by step than that? I'm not following

Comment: The answer below by mathguy should do the trick...